# TfsMigrator: "VS4032856: The identity ** belongs to a different Azure Active Directory (AAD) tenant"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, tfs-migration

When trying to migrate from TFS to Azure Devops I run in an error during the import phase :

> [Error] VS4032856: The identity Rémi Benoit belongs to a different Azure     Active Directory (AAD) tenant than the identity used during the prepare step. Please sign in with an identity in the same AAD tenant or re-run the prepare step using this identity.

The user I used for the prepare step is registered on the AAD tenant. I can login to Azure portal with it and read user details on the AAD page of the portal.

A possible problem: my user was created on a different tenant. I was then invited as a guest to the tenant domain used in the import. I can list all the users on the AAD from the Azure portal. I also changed my default Azure directory to the tenant of the import.

Should I use an account created specifically on the AAD to execute the import ? Or Am I just missing some rights ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem by using another account.

Switched from using a guest account to a member account on the AAD.